# Completion Issues

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

So I am trying to implement a revelaingSplashView for my initial view controller. My initial vc has a couple of database calls that seem to complete in a weird order. After some tracing I have narrowed it down to the specific function that occurs last as far as the completion blocks go. Which I have listed here

```
@objc func grabFriendsEvents(){
    print("Attempting to see where your friends are going")
    UserService.following { (user) in
        for following in user {
            print(following.username as Any)
            PostService.showFollowingEvent(for: following.uid, completion: { (event) in
                self.friendsEvents.append(event)
               // self.friendsEvents.append(contentsOf: event)
                // leave here
                self.friendsEvents = self.friendsEvents.removeDuplicates()
                print("ending in friends events")
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })

        }  

    }
}
```

The two supporting functions in the service methods that I have implemented are listed below.

```
static func following(for user: User = User.current, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
    // 1
    let followingRef = Database.database().reference().child("following").child(user.uid)
    followingRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // 2
        guard let followingDict = snapshot.value as? [String : Bool] else {
            return completion([])
        }

        // 3
        var following = [User]()
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for uid in followingDict.keys {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            show(forUID: uid) { user in
                if let user = user {
                    following.append(user)
                }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }

        // 4
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(following)
        }
    })
}
```

The second one is listed here

```
static func showFollowingEvent(for followerKey: String,completion: @escaping (Event) -> Void) {
    //getting firebase root directory
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(followerKey).child("Attending").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (attendingSnapshot) in
        print(attendingSnapshot)
        guard var eventKeys = attendingSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else{return}
        for event in eventKeys{
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            EventService.show(forEventKey: event.key, completion: { (event) in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
                completion(event!)
            })
        }
    }) { (err) in
        print("couldn't grab event info",err)

    }
}
```

Now the grabFriendsEvents returns a couple times depending on the number of friends you have and the events that they are attending. Im trying to figure out the way to know when that is complete so I can dismiss the revealing view. I think dispatch groups might be the way to go but Im not sure exactly where to put it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In grabFriendsEvents: PostService.showFollowingEvent is also an asyn function getting called in a cycle, so you need to add a dispatch queue for it too.

   ```
   let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
   for following in user {
       print(following.username as Any)
       dispatchGroup.enter()
       PostService.showFollowingEvent(for: following.uid, completion: { (event) in
           self.friendsEvents.append(event)
          // self.friendsEvents.append(contentsOf: event)
           // leave here
           self.friendsEvents = self.friendsEvents.removeDuplicates()
           print("ending in friends events")
           self.collectionView?.reloadData()
           dispatchGroup.leave()
       })

   } 
   dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
       // dismiss the revealing view
   }
   ```
2. In showFollowingEvent you never call dispatchGroup.notify, that is the reason of it firing multiple times
3. I know it may not be possible, but it's best to restructure API calls

Comment: should I restructure all my api calls like the method you just showed

Comment: this crashed it on like the fifth or fourth iteration of the loop btw

Comment: I think with those two it has to enter the same amount of times it left

Comment: il take a further look into it seems to be leaving 7 times but entering 6 times pretty weird